# c++ set size not corresponds to number of its elements

Tags: c++, openmp

I have here a very interesting problem here using parallel libraries of OMP, I'm running into a weird case, where std::set do not return the exact number of elements of the set.  Actually

1. I'm taking a `vector<set<int> >`, after it
2. I take a random element of this vector, which is a std::set, and randomly add or delete an element (random number from 1 to N)
3. I check the size of set using two methods

   - a Using "size" function of `std::set`
   - Iterating through all elements of set, and computing number of iterations

Finally this two methods return different results, when I'm using more than one thread. If you have some ideas how could it arrive, please leave a comment
Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   srand(time(NULL));
   int N = atoi(argv[1]);      //Number of elements
   vector<int> RI(N);          //Random Indexes
   vector<int> RV(N);          //Random Values
   vector<set<int> > VSI(N);   //vector of sets (main object)


   for(int i=0;i<N;i++)        //Assignement of Random Indexes and Values 
      {RI[i] = rand()%N; RV[i] = rand()%N;}


   int nproc = atoi(argv[2]);  //Number of threads 

#pragma omp parallel for shared(N), num_threads(nproc)
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)        //Random Changing of elements of VSI
   {
      int r = RV[i];
      if(r%4 == 0)      {VSI[RI[i]].insert(r); VSI[N-RI[i]-1].insert(r);}
      else if(r%4 == 1) {VSI[RI[i]].insert(r); VSI[N-RI[i]-1].erase(r); }
      else if(r%4 == 2) {VSI[RI[i]].erase(r);  VSI[N-RI[i]-1].insert(r);}
      else              {VSI[RI[i]].erase(r);  VSI[N-RI[i]-1].erase(r); }
   }


  vector<int> RealSize(N);    //Here will be calculated the real size of sets
  for(int i=0;i<N;i++)        //passing through all sets
     {
         RealSize[i] = 0;        //passing through all elements of set i
         for(set<int>::iterator it = VSI[i].begin();it != VSI[i].end(); it++)
         RealSize[i]++;        //computing number of element
     }


 for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    if(VSI[i].size() != RealSize[i])
      {
          cout<<"Error in set N_"<<i<<endl<<"Elements of this are:---";
          for(set<int>::iterator it = VSI[i].begin();it != VSI[i].end(); it++)
          cout<<*it<<", ";
          cout<<endl<<"Size given by set.size is:   "<<VSI[i].size()<<"   Real Size is:   "<<RealSize[i]<<endl;
      }
}
```

And as I'm getting for example the following output

```
Error in set N_73
Elements of this are:---5, 58, 
Size given by set.size is:   6   Real Size is:   2
```

Comment: None of STL containers including `std::set` are thread safe, so you have to properly guard access to them in multithreaded environment (either by exclusive mutex or read/write one). Or you can use thread safe containers either lock free or not.

Comment: @Slava this is the correct answer as to what's happening. Make it into an answer and you have my upvote.

Comment: Thank you very much Slava
I totally agree with you, I studied this problem all day, and I've mentioned that it's not the problem of the size, the problem was that the std::set.begin() do not return the real "begin" of the set, and this is due to "thread no-safety".

Thank you very much one more time.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong in the sense that several threads can update the shared resource (namely `VSI`) at the same time without synchronisation.
You have therefore a race condition in your parallel loop.
I guess you can fix this with the use of `critical` OpenMP directive as follow:

```
#pragma omp parallel for shared(N), num_threads(nproc)
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)        //Random Changing of elements of VSI
   {
      int r = RV[i];
      if(r%4 == 0)
          #pragma omp critical
          {VSI[RI[i]].insert(r); VSI[N-RI[i]-1].insert(r);}
      else if(r%4 == 1)
          #pragma omp critical
          {VSI[RI[i]].insert(r); VSI[N-RI[i]-1].erase(r); }
      else if(r%4 == 2)
          #pragma omp critical
          {VSI[RI[i]].erase(r);  VSI[N-RI[i]-1].insert(r);}
      else
          #pragma omp critical
          {VSI[RI[i]].erase(r);  VSI[N-RI[i]-1].erase(r); }
   }
```

I tested this and it seems to work. However, I'm not 100% sure this is correct as this would be the first time for me that I use critical sections inside an if construct this way.
Hope this helps.

Gilles

Comment: Thank you very much Gilles
I understood that the problem was that two threads was accessing simultaneously to the object (std:set), which is not thread-safe as @Slava mentioned in comments.
I didn't know about "OpenMP CRITICAL Directive", this really solves my problem, so Thank you one more time!

Comment: Glad it works. That is really what `critical` is for, putting some locks around a block of instructions to make sure that only one single thread at a time executes.